# Отсортировать текст из файла построчно по 50 элементов в строке. Разбить на блоки и вывести их в несколько рядов

Tags: c#, строки

Необработанное исключение: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Индекс и показание счетчика должны указывать на позицию в строке.
Жалуется на 65 строку кода. А конкретнее на строку:

```
FinalTxt = FinalTxt.Remove(((countStrPage * length) * (countPage - 1));
```

Суть в том, что мне нужно сначала отсортировать текст построчно. По 50 элементов в строке. Это есть.
А потом разбить текст на блоки и вывести их в несколько рядов.

В моем файле 2000 элементов ровно.
По-этому брал значения countPage = 4 , countStrPage = 10.

**Если вам не нравится мой ход мыслей по поводу такого разложения блоков, предложите свой**

```
{
            Console.WriteLine("Укажите количество страниц в вашей книге");
            int countPage = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Укажите количетсво строк в странице");
            int countStrPage = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            string text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\lab5.txt");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();

            string finalTxt = "";
            int length = 50; //Количетсво символов в строке
            int n = 1; //для переноса строки

            string[] blocks = new string[countPage];


            // Сначало разобьем текст на строки

            for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
            {

                if (i == length * n)
                {
                    n += 1;
                    finalTxt += "\r\n";
                    finalTxt += text[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    finalTxt += text[i];

                }
            }

            
 
            //Теперь разобьем его на блоки

            for (int i = countPage - 1; i > -1; i--)
            {
                // Количество элемнтов на одной странице countStrPage * length ( кол-во строк на длину ) это будет один блок.
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    blocks[i] = finalTxt;
                    break;
                }
    
                blocks[i] = finalTxt.Substring((countStrPage * length) * (countPage - 1));
                finalTxt = finalTxt.Remove(((countStrPage * length) * (countPage - 1)), ((countStrPage * length) * countPage));
                countPage -= 1;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < countPage; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(blocks[i] + "\t");
            }

        }
```

Comment: Тот случай, когда комментарий комплиментарен коду: `lenght // Количетсво`

Comment: @vp_arth  я могу заменить все , просто на значение 50, но это ничего не даст

Comment: Советы: Правильно пишется `length`, а не `lenght`, и если количество, то вообще `count` (счёт, количество) или `amount` (всего, количество). Потому что `length` в переводе на русский - "длина". И рекомендуется называть переменные понятными именами, а не `k`, `k1`, так будет проще читать ваш код. Классы, свойства и методы следует называть с большой буквы, а локальные переменные - с маленькой. То есть должно быть `blocks`, а не `Blocks` и `finalText`, а не `FinalTxt`. Таков общепринятый стандарт именования в C#.

Comment: @aepot Извините.Не знал об этом. Только на первом курсе учусь пока

Comment: Так я вас и не ругаю, я вам подсказываю.

Comment: @aepot сейчас исправлю :)

Comment: @aepor надеюсь так лучше

Comment: Лучше. Ок, раз уж начали `snake_case` не принято в C#, принято только 2 вида написаний: `camelCase` и `PascalCase`. Вот [ссылка](https://habr.com/ru/post/26077/), здесь подробнее описано.

Comment: @aepot То есть CountPage и CountStrPage? или как?

Comment: Проще :) `pagesCount` и `linesPerPage`

Comment: @aepot ну получается , что теперь нормально))

Comment: Отлично, вот так код проще читается. По поводу ответа, вы выражения Linq проходили? Пример входных данных можете показать?

Comment: @aepot вообще нет

Comment: Сразу можно ссылку на [рекомандации от MS](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions) кидать

Comment: @aepot Но если вы напишите ответ , с помощью такого метода, я постараюсь разобраться

Comment: Чтобы написать ответ, надо понять вопрос. Пока он не понятен, что есть блоки? Типа слова, разделены пробелами? Сортировка построчно, значит исходный текст надо разбить на строки, так? Или входной текст - это типа одна строка, но надо разбить по 50 элементов в строке, или как? Но сначала давайте определимся, что такое блок.

Comment: вообщем мы берем текст и делим его как бы на страницы , просто я назвал их блоки))

Comment: @aepot сортировать текст. Имеется в виду в каждой стоке должно быть одинаковое количество символов. Вообще оно в ручную устанавливается , но мы взяли фиксированное 50

Comment: @aepot вообще текст такой у меня в файле:

Comment: @aepot нет , извините он слишком длинный. А файл видимо прикрепить нельзя

Comment: Отсортировать буквы в строке, так? Типа `аааабббввввггг`? 50 символов в строке, так? Строки разделены `\r\n`, а страницы чем?

Comment: @aepot нет. Мы не меняем буквы местами никак,  просто после каждых 50 элементов отступаем строку в выводе. Создаем как бы столбик

Comment: Тогда это не сортировка, а разбиение на строки. Сортировка - это там, где меняется порядок чего-либо.

Comment: @aepot тогда моя ошибка

Comment: @aepot Я не нашел кода, который бы просто брал, отделял от строки нужную нам часть и присваивал. Может вы знаете?

Comment: @aepot Можно вообще полностью когда переписать. И сделать чтобы он сначала делил вот весь текст на страницы. А потом уже в выводе сделать построчное разделение

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115423/discussion-on-question-by-thedesiretobelieve-----).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кажется получилось, с использованием `StringBuilder` как накопителя текста для страницы.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Укажите количество страниц в вашем тексте: ");
    int countPage = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Укажите количетсво строк в странице: ");
    int countStrPage = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    //string text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\lab5.txt");

    //Так как файла с данными у меня нет, я использую генератор случайных букв.
    //Удалите следующие 5 строк и раскомментируйте чтение из файла у себя.
    char[] chars = new char[2000];
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
        chars[i] = (char)rnd.Next('a', 'z' + 1);
    string text = new string(chars);

    int length = 50; // длина строки
    int j = 0; // счетчик страниц

    string[] blocks = new string[countPage];
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(text[i]);

        if ((i + 1) % length == 0) // если конец строки
        {
            if ((i + 1) / length % countStrPage == 0) // если конец страницы 
            {
                blocks[j] = sb.ToString();
                sb.Clear();
                j++;
                if (j == countPage) // если все страницы заполнены, выход из цикла, на случай если входных данных больше, чем нужно
                    break;
            }
            else
                sb.AppendLine();
        }
    }

    int blocksPerLine = Console.BufferWidth / (length + 1);
    int cursorTop = Console.CursorTop;

    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
        int cursorLeft = i % blocksPerLine * (length + 1);
        if (cursorLeft == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            cursorTop = Console.CursorTop;
        }
        else
            Console.CursorTop = cursorTop;

        string[] lines = blocks[i].Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            Console.CursorLeft = cursorLeft;
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
Укажите количество страниц в вашем тексте: 4
Укажите количетсво строк в странице: 10

sxkttdbkmfbgakbobhqaheipuhxfsvyffmmeyirnlohompdgvh zwzibtxymzayzrarbxdajdxesdzdtvwiemkzefxkkxnczntcsg
tlertopvylgwrrhwaoxwqsqcoswucfeqjlbmaosxpcjghpwqgq unmyrwzvpyuufrcsunganwasqlpuefjxlmaivfvnzipyqqsvzh
pojzrbvccasvsthpmgpuvlvzhnijuzwfnmqphkuarxmsftkqys tgvrtynuifgeqjoxisrtwossaegbbasuvxmdbttbvbwpgvsgkt
cqaludsjrdtlhcemifdrhblpcxzduncrlcxffbsmwytqhgqjot hzefkeocrormsimmjtxlvpzpyvrcmfmaristppmioycekiioct
lengkbfkiweppebbzffzggnqviiviwhqpabyeervausvihjopf lziyxrzogpmlqlbqvkptwtgowxnvfqmdastnrskbtbjxvdiqct
gkdpmfrxlbsjcmonzocdxvnjymnrhnztfdpxmanwggspdqsghu nyyiwssucaeeiqdilyroycaoavkistowsmcnervbuxqjwossun
hummhkxtqzrzqxcyezwrbzafwqdxgiugkmgehtvezsknehqvne rkyoukykibhjbjlhmwopeucptamqrldsofbeydrrpuiuukwgxp
mtjpthugprhznhflpdrxrkdsripmbpzikbvbxusykaddwafcit cveejxhivtyhsxypvvhgjifwzjliviefscihnkwdxpixtibkve
smdpncprylshfarzollenulsnqgzvqcmehxnevotmgwhgdudmx pbyqguphfzlznmpsoqpqblyejuzidriamrscgbvnrgexrycvib
muqegxblbwvpvhifdydevtwrrhxdmkwdnyeiwzbzlstsywkpza tkvfcecuhmuhenqkmvumlmubzvgbmlrezcxxfhooamujtjbrgg

lgbvpgptghyaiwuqhcptffhgmyslipupvfzldemqhlagpadypd uwkktwoylygluzdeaftfvtznwmzxhfltgdignylskojpbvrjqw
bzbmbfyujqoelqnjecwimdqzlteaqmvuvfnvoietnivvcdaktg kvwhkaxwogwrrgmnerqxqcuauhkjmauqhkuqwzsijqkewtwddo
vbbgqyibbhaxexvuifdsuvycvdivxhsuhkqtspppmmhwtpexzh qassgiavmdqnknmgjhlwqfyiozspebkhgxjtyoelpbmosvgwsp
uvgblzcylmpnetogqtgbctqnfiocjgykvpmxngyrrueczyhnhm jprhylcjegqkrltihmdshvdagpsjqstvxorupyzxrojxvejbvj
zkrxfbetvckzoeofrphrsjvpkipoohbbvwgotyklsulvgrfzot ntsziomrajtstlmvndtytjnfbtlfebfqogfacygdiyxqezuyla
hsgquppcnxmqfobiesyzmtfvyxyziscpauzjvfbqyqlmycpxuy rghxqefnyocgmzdddnglsowqpvlxbbznuejzjrqbuparaclymb
nmaohnnkrxrqtuuwqkosnzqhbviswwhbfkfpommlvlnezhxqsb vhszhdjqhusilwppmipeumwerdoeqnkmkafruuwgpsjvimddck
leibkowtmlfunvpqljpehexcwcllhtyrzvkcsdzrtvzbgbxroj pdjihjknieoeaukgxlqxusliobdavfzkcfxgdctwhhmsrkrolc
wnbnthggeicklsnovslmyhjylmewwvetwywkplbdvlyqoijgnr osnfqxrbtffjrdfecvwdcvrtqnftqekoptrgxwpzpcjoqxpjmn
ffgckpedchckkjeionvcyjrhqmisjcdyjepynunhgmjualbpmg hwshzsatocrykovruylyhggxoamddtywgdwnwitygdhmiqrusz
```

Comment: спасибо большое. Сейчас свой код дописать новый  еще попробую , если ничего не выйдет возьму ваш :#

Comment: @TheDesireToBelieve в любом случае разберите, как работает. Как по мне, оно выглядит намного проще, чем то что в вопросе.

Comment: Я знаю что вам покажется это глупым вопросом, но почему мы берем 
if ((i + 1) % length == 0) // если конец строки 
if ((i + 1) / length % countStrPage == 0) // если конец страницы

Comment: @TheDesireToBelieve а вы подставьте любое значение вместо `i` и посчитайте на калькуляторе. К примеру `i = 49`, тогда остаток от деления 50 на 50 будет 0, то же самое 100 на 50, и т.д. Со страницами тоже самое, только считаем не символы, а строки.

Comment: Я вижу вы разбираетесь. А можно ли реализовать вывод в 2 колонки?

Comment: получается что есть два столбика. Где слева будут масивы нечетные , а справа четные

Comment: @TheDesireToBelieve увидел в задании, что блоки надо по несколько штук в строку выводить, исправил вывод. Стандартная длина строки в консоли `Console.BufferWidth` - 120 символов, следовательно влезает 2 блока. Если длина строки будет меньше, влезет больше. Алгоритм это учитывает.

Comment: пойду разбираться , точно скажут что не сам писал))

Comment: Спасибо вам большое , научили и оформлению и коду :D

Comment: @TheDesireToBelieve исправил баг при выводе, было исключение, если пользователь запросил страниц больше, чем можно заполнить данными. Теперь все норм.