# C# - Как поместить заданное кол-во мин рандомом в массиве

Tags: c#

Сразу говорю, я новичок в c#. У меня есть задача сделать типа сапера, но который сразу открывает решение.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Введите ширину поля: ");
            int q = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Введите длину поля: ");
            int w = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Введите число мин: ");
            int c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            Random rand = new Random();

            var charArray = new char[q, w];
            var intArray = new int[q, w];
            for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < w; j++)
                {
                    intArray[i, j] = rand.Next(2);
                    charArray[i, j] = intArray[i, j] == 0 ? '_' : '*';
                    Console.Write(charArray[i, j]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Должны вывестись две матрицы. На первой должно быть все закрыто, то есть должны быть только символы: _ и *

0 - это места без мин, заменил я их символом _

1 - это места с минами, заменил я их символом звездочки, но они не принимают введеное пользователем количество мин. А нужно, чтобы символов "*" было столько, сколько и мин.

А во второй матрице должно вывестись уже открытое решение игры. То есть ячейки, рядом с которыми есть мины, должны принять число, значущее кол-во мин рядом с этой ячейкой.

Помогите, пожалуйста..

[image: Текущий код после компиляции]

Comment: Ну, вы почитали это `c`, и не использовали его ни разу. Вопрос конкретно в чем? Просьба дописать за вас решение здесь - не формат для вопросов. Конкретизируйте вопрос. Рекомендую давать переменным более осмысленные имена, так будет легче читать код.

Comment: @aepot я  хочу узнать как или каким именно способом можно использовать c, чтобы соответствовал заданию

Comment: Про вывод нескольких массивов рядом алгоритм есть [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1194110/373567).

Comment: @aepot, спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще вся задача сводится к тому, чтобы сгенерировать `c` случайных уникальных чисел. И потом используя эти числа расставить единички в массиве. Сам алгоритм генерации и расстановки можно реализовать разными способами, и способ зависит от ваших знаний и контекста задания. Есть один гарантированный способ это сделать эффективно в случае если размер матрицы небольшой, скажем меньше миллиона элементов.

Нужно взять массив длиной в количество элементов матрицы, заполнить его индексами этих элементов и перемешать, затем взять нужное количество элементов с начала массива. Задача очень просто решается с помощью Linq, но я попробую без этого.

```cs
int rows = 10;
int cols = 10;
int minesCount = 5;

int[] indexes = new int[rows * cols];
// заполняю индексами
for (int i = 0; i < indexes.Length; i++)
{
    indexes[i] = i;
}
Random rnd = new Random();
// перемешиваю
for (int i = 0; i < indexes.Length; i++)
{
    int randomIndex = rnd.Next(indexes.Length);
    int x = indexes[randomIndex];
    indexes[randomIndex] = indexes[i];
    indexes[i] = x;
}
```

Теперь можно считать, что массив `indexes` содержит уникальные случайные числа. Алгоритм описан хорошо в [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0).

Чтобы получить координаты в матрице, нужно применить формулу, по которой номер строки - это результат деления индекса на количество колонок на цело, а номер колонки - остаток от этого деления.

```
int[,] matrix = new int[rows, cols];
for (int i = 0; i < minesCount; i++)
{
    int index = indexes[i];
    int row = index / cols;
    int col = index % cols;
    matrix[row, col] = 1;
}
```

Теперь можно вывести матрицу в консоль.

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(matrix[i, j]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Пример вывода в консоль

```
0000001000
0000000010
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0100000000
1000000000
0000000010
```

При этом вам не нужно хранить матрицу с символами, она будет дублировать данные матрицы с числами, а дублирование данных в приложении - всегда плохо. Это источник лишних ошибок. Чтобы вывести звездочки с подчеркиваниями можно сделать просто вот так.

```cs
Console.Write(matrix[i, j] == 1 ? '*' : '_');
```

Либо изначально можно хранить матрицу с не с числами, а с символами. Но при условии, что вы собрались делать сапёра, это может оказаться не очень удобным.

---

Обратите внимание, что при условии что `x` - это координата по горизонтали, `matrix[x, y]` это неверная нотация, верная `matrix[y, x]`. Потому что первый индекс указывает на номер строки, а второй - на номер колонки, а строки же располагаются по высоте, одна за другой.

Чтобы не путаться, советую делать как я `matrix[row, col]`. В вашем примере `q` - это ширина, так? А вот и нет, вы считываете ширину, но задаете ее как высоту, и наоборот. Попробуйте задать разные `q` и `w`, например 5 и 10, и вы убедитесь в этом сами на практике.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!!! Все предельно ясно и понятно теперь.